# t1lib-dev on Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: ubuntu, apt, ubuntu-14.10

I used to be able to install t1lib with apt-get install t1lib-dev.

Ubuntu websites says they still have it but I just can't install it.

Even when I compile PHP I get this:

configure: error: Your t1lib distribution is not installed correctly. Please reinstall it.

Is there a solution?

I am using Ubuntu 14.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[t1lib was removed from Ubuntu 14.10](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/t1lib/+bug/1352999) because [it was removed from Debian](https://bugs.debian.org/744881), which is upstream of Ubuntu. And it was removed from Debian because it [appears to have been abandoned by its upstream maintainers, and has years worth of security issues](https://bugs.debian.org/637488).

It is probably not coming back. The t1lib web site hasn't been updated in so long that its download links are dead, and have been dead for almost a decade.

You should plan now to move to alternative libraries, if you even need Type 1 support at all (which is unlikely). Modern systems generally use freetype2.